# Can I import OpenOffice.org settings into LibreOffice?

Tags: openoffice, migration, import, libreoffice

I'm considering migrating from OpenOffice.org to LibreOffice, and I want to make sure LibreOffice picks up all of the settings and customizations I've made.  Will LibreOffice read the user profile automatically, or do I need to take any action to keep my settings when I migrate?

Comment: "no need to apologize DragonLord. we're all here to learn together. :)" @studiohack, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import your settings from OpenOffice by copying the profile directory, location varies by platform:

- Windows: C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\OpenOffice
- Linux ~/.openoffice (not on linux to test)
- Mac: /registry/data/org/openoffice

Just copy all folders contained there to the LibreOffice folders in the same location.

Comment: I simply renamed the OpenOffice.org folder to LibreOffice (which has the same effect), and it worked.  Thanks :)

Comment: I tried what Mud said in a Debian gnu/linux system, and Libreoffice wouldn't start afterwards. The subdirectories in the .libreoffice directory are not identical to the ones in the .openoffice.org directory. If you try this, be sure to save your .libreoffice directory so you can restore it.

Answer (score 2):

I just installed LibreOffice 3.4.5 to try it out on a Windows 7 (64bit) laptop, unselecting the 'Use as default' for each of the MSOffice components, so it would not disturb my Openoffice 3.3.0 configuration.

To my surprise, LibreOffice took over and now is the default for my .doc, .xls, .ppt files. 
All of my Openoffice configuration was copied, including the extensions that I had installed.

Fortunately it all works!